# Перевести unix время в обычное python

Tags: python

Как мне перевести unix время, в формат наподобие 12:00:00, без даты.

Comment: Пример, из чего во что

Comment: Очень просто - открыть документацию модуля по работе со временем и найти нам нужную функцию. Это займёт у тебя минут пять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевести unix время в обычное python можно с помощью  модуля datetime

```py
import datetime

unix_time = '1705153267'
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_time)).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_time)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

```
17:41:07                # Время
2024-01-13 17:41:07     # Дата и время
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]